# Django strange behavior: infinite loading all views, but django is working

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

2 years experience with Django (1.8.12, Ubuntu 14.04) and faced this problem 1st time.

After some time (not sure why) i come to my site and tried to load some page: **result is infinite loading all views** including admin panel (cannot login) and all external views. Browser tab shows loading circle and never loads.

Super strange is the following: i tried add\remove some apps from settings.py, make mistakes in my code, add\erase some imports and when i do this Django start working normally: it shows me standard error page (yellow-gray with traceback). Then i go to code and fix mistake - infinite loading arise again.

*Once today i was able to get my view working - it is loaded normally (simple view with form). But is is impossible to reload this view second time - it loads once and after that i got infinite loading again all other tries.*

In Apache *error.log* i see:

```
    [Tue Feb 07 19:50:23.776657 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16966 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:23.776852 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16967 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:25.779159 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16966 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:25.779280 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16967 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:27.781572 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16966 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:27.781704 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00045: child process 16967 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:29.784028 2017] [core:error] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00046: child process 16966 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:29.784174 2017] [core:error] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00046: child process 16967 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:30.785515 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16963:tid 139669519046528] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.628188 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 17265:tid 140333802358656] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 10.1.1.163:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.649372 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 17266:tid 140333802358656] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 10.1.1.163:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.649851 2017] [:warn] [pid 17266:tid 140333802358656] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0.
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.649872 2017] [:warn] [pid 17266:tid 140333802358656] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.651402 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17266:tid 140333802358656] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:31.651466 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17266:tid 140333802358656] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:33.728378 2017] [:error] [pid 17270:tid 140333668648704] /usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
[Tue Feb 07 19:50:33.728432 2017] [:error] [pid 17270:tid 140333668648704]   return f(*args, **kwds)
```

What i tried: remove .pyc files, mod_wsgi update. Django migrate is working.

Comment: are you already restarted the apache? what going on?

Comment: @SancaKembang yes, many times restarted the apache, nothing good)

Comment: how many projects that is in your server now? did you tried it with once apache and multiple python versions?

Comment: @SancaKembang - only 1 project, didn't tried, use only python 3.4

Answer (score 3):

Solution is https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22948

I have added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to apache config.
Still not sure why this problem arise

Comment: It is mentioned in the mod_wsgi documentation at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api You are using some Python package which uses a C extension that will not work in Python sub interpreters properly.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - Maybe you are right: my guess that this started to happen after installing machine learning packages TensorFlow, Keras, Theano. But when i remove them problem didn't disappear. What do you mean "Python sub interpreters properly" - in production i use Python 3.4 only. Ubuntu also have 2.7, but i didn't install there anything new

Comment: It is a feature of Python whereby within a process, you create more than one interpreter space, where each is supposed to operate separately. In mod_wsgi it uses these to separate different WSGI application from each other. Some modules such as ``numpy`` don't use the specific threading APIs in the Python C library which would allow them to work in these sub interpreters. That directive forces everything to run in the main interpreter context of a process, which is the same as what would occur if it was command line Python. The simplified Python threading APIs used will then work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was searching for hours for a solution of infinite loading in my Python application running on Apache server.